Sequelize typescript package one-to-many relation inserts foreign key on each sync with alter table
This is the model definition of my User model :
import {
    Table,
    Column,
    Model,
    DataType,
    PrimaryKey,
    AutoIncrement,
    ForeignKey,
    BelongsTo,
    HasMany,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Role } from './Roles';
import { UserGroupLink } from './UserGroupLink';
import { Validation } from './Validations';

@Table({
    tableName: 'Users',
    timestamps: false,
})
export class User extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'ID',
    })
    id!: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'Name',
    })
    email!: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Role)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'RoleID',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    roleId!: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Role, {
        foreignKey: 'roleId',
        targetKey: 'id',
        as: 'role',
    })
    role!: Role;

    @HasMany(() => UserGroupLink, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'userGroupLinks',
    })
    userGroupLinks!: UserGroupLink[];

    @HasMany(() => Validation, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'validations',
    })
    validations!: Validation[];
}

and this is the model definition of my Role model :
import { Table, Column, Model, DataType, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, HasMany } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { User } from './Users';

@Table({
    tableName: 'Roles',
    timestamps: false,
})
export class Role extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'ID',
    })
    id!: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'Name',
    })
    name!: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.TEXT,
        field: 'Description',
    })
    description!: string | null;

    @HasMany(() => User, {
        sourceKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'roleId',
        as: 'users',
    })
    users!: User[];
}

Basically what i want to achieve is to make a one to many relation ship between role and user models, one role can have many users but one user can only have one role
This way the relation is correct, i can insert and query for users with role or role with users, the problem is every time the server starts and sequelize.sync({alter: true}) runs, it inserts a new foreign key to users pointing to roles table
enter image description here
According to this issue: "https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/266"
i've tried modifying my user model like this:
import {
    Table,
    Column,
    Model,
    DataType,
    PrimaryKey,
    AutoIncrement,
    ForeignKey,
    BelongsTo,
    HasMany,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Role } from './Roles';
import { UserGroupLink } from './UserGroupLink';
import { Validation } from './Validations';

@Table({
    tableName: 'Users',
    timestamps: false,
})
export class User extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'ID',
    })
    id!: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'Name',
    })
    email!: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Role)
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED)
    public roleId!: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Role, {
        foreignKey: 'roleId',
    })
    public role!: Role;

    @HasMany(() => UserGroupLink, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'userGroupLinks',
    })
    userGroupLinks!: UserGroupLink[];

    @HasMany(() => Validation, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'validations',
    })
    validations!: Validation[];
}

but the foreign keys still got inserted

Maybe it's time to look at migrations?
